# Can we combine all iterations in one output, using for LOOP in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I have a symbolic matrix and I want to substitute different values row wise. I used `for` loop which substituted values row wise in every iteration. But how can I combine these iterations to get a matrix?

e.g. `A=[x  x^2;x^3  x^4]` is a symbolic matrix of two rows, I want to submit 1 in row one and 2 in row two using `for` loop and I want a matrix of two rows with substitution. Without for loop its very simple but in case of higher dimension matrices `for` loop is useful.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you require an iterative solution for row specific substitution in a symbolic matrix and collect all results in a numerical matrix. This can be achieved like this :

```
% Define symbolic variables
syms x
A = [x x^2; x^3 x^4];

% substitution values of x for each row
xvals = [1 2];

% iterative substitution in symbolic expression
[Ar,Ac,Ad] = size(A);   % Use Ac, Ad for higher dim. matrices if needed
res = zeros(size(A));   % Collect results

for i=1:Ar
    x = xvals(i);
    res(i,:) = subs(A(i,:));
end
```

Based on your requirement you can define a higher dim. symbolic matrix and numerical matrix and use `res(i,:,k) = subs(A(i,:,k)) where k=1:Ad` in the loop for substitution.

Comment: Absolutely Right. Sir as you suggested to add "k" for higher dimension, should this be inserted as another loop(Nested Loop) or as another statement in the same loop?